# High excel cpu and memory usage

Tags: microsoft-excel, memory, cpu

When I try to filter an excel table with approx 36000 rows I takes a long while to calculate. When I look at the processor and memory usage, I notice the cpu usage is at 100% and the memory usage around 60%.

The document has multiple sheets and the sheet containing the table has lookups to other sheets.

I already tried [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3ac26a70-8db5-4e44-ba2c-e217cc5ae92c/excel-2010-high-memory-usage?forum=excel):

1. ForceFullCalculation set to true
2. Switch off multi-threaded recalculation

So I already know it's because Excel needs to recalculate all the lookups in the table.

What options are there to have a better working experience?

Comment: Go through your formulas: 1. make sure any array type formulas limit the references to only the cells with data, no full column references.  2. that you are avoiding volatile functions (OFFSET,INDIRECT,...).

Comment: we can't debug this because Microsoft doesn't provide debug symbols for Office products. phone the Microsoft support for help.

Comment: Make sure everything actually needs to be recalculated.  Often in huge spreadsheets, much of what's there doesn't change for each recalculation.

Comment: @ScottCraner checked both, not sure if vlookup is a volatile function, but that's the function that consumes all my cpu

Comment: @fixer1234 Not sure what you imply with your comment, I already tried turning of recalculation